# How can I get the return value of function in c++

Tags: c++, authentication

I usually try not to ask questions, but this has had me stumped for a while. So my question is how can I check the value of string HomeWTD in a "if Statement" in the following code?

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Header.h"

using namespace Header;

void main()
{
    Home();
    if (NEED HELP HERE)
    {
    }
}
```

Header.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>

//Create A Namespace called "Header"
namespace Header
{
    using namespace std;
}

//Functions
string Home()
{
    string HomeWTD;
    string LoginTxt = "Login";
    string RegisterTxt = "Register";
    string OptionsTxt = "Options";
    string CreditsTxt = "Credits";
    string QuitTxt = "Quit";
    string HomeHeaderMsg = "   Home   ";

    cout << HomeHeaderMsg;
    cout << "----------" << endl;
    cout << LoginTxt << endl;
    cout << RegisterTxt << endl;
    cout << OptionsTxt << endl;
    cout << CreditsTxt << endl;
    cout << QuitTxt << endl << endl;

    getline(cin, HomeWTD);

    return HomeWTD;
}

void Register()
{
    string UsernameIn;
    string PasswordIn;
    string UsernameOut;
    string PasswordOut;

    getline(cin, UsernameIn);
    getline(cin, PasswordIn);

    ofstream UserFile;
    UserFile.open(UsernameIn + ".UserSav");
    UserFile << PasswordIn;
};
```

Comment: so you didn't fancy trying a basic C++ tutorial?

Comment: `namespace Header { using namespace std; }` what.

Comment: I was planning to add more to that, just not now.

Comment: Do you really think it's efficient to learn a language via StackOverflow?

Comment: use `int main` not `void main`.  Define your functions in `.cpp` files and declare them in `.h` files.  Don't `using namespace` in a header file, just write `std::string`.  Wrap your header files in [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard#Use_of_.23include_guards)

Comment: `if (NEED HELP HERE)` I cannot find a way in your program for this conditional to evaluate to `true`, so I can only assume that you are not in need of assistance this evening. So long!

Comment: @EJP: As long as all those muppets below keep answering questions like this? Yeah, he will think that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nice to be called a muppet...  I answered because it was just as easy as it would have been to cause a fuss.

Comment: @paddy: Read [this](http://slash7.com/pages/vampires) please.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `#define NEED "a"` `#define HELP "b"` `#define HERE "c"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either save the result and compare later:

```
string result = Home();
if( result == "foo" ) {
    ...
}
```

Or use the result inline:

```
if( Home() == "foo" ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I got the error: expression must have bool type or be convertable to bool.

Comment: The binary string operator `==` returns a bool.  You either have not done what I suggested or the error is in some other part of your code.

Comment: The other possibility is that you have errors before that.  For example, `string` not existing in your main program.  You import the `std` namespace in your header under the `Header` namespace.  I'm not convinced it will be there by default when you import the `Header` namespace.  Try `using namespace std;` in your cpp file, or fully qualify `string` to `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "Header.h"

using namespace Header;

void main()
{
    string answer = Home();
    if (answer == "something")
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Using `Home()` is like just using the value of HomeWTD.

Comment: You are calling the function twice.  Given that the OP is already struggling to understand C++, this will give them the wrong idea.

Comment: @paddy Oh, I thought that would work.  How can I fix it?

Comment: @paddy nevermind.  I know how to fix it.

Comment: Do you actually feel qualified to be answering C++ questions?

Comment: @paddy Yes, I have answered other questions.  I am also on a different forum, and I give the right answer a lot of times.  I just messed up once.  Also, I have made a program that has stuff like this alot.  Just noticed you answered there question with something that is almost exactly what I have.

Comment: Erm, are you suggesting that I copied you before you even wrote your answer, let alone corrected it?  I was more concerned with your comment saying you "thought it would work".

Comment: @paddy No, I know you did not copy my answer.  I had misunderstood what you meant by your second comment.  I thought you had said that I shouldn't be answering questions because I was way off.  I thought I knew it would work, but it turns out I did not.  I am sorry about the misunderstanding.